# Are all prime numbers finite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers

If we answer false, then there must be an infinite prime number. But infinity is not a number and we have a contradiction. If we answer true, then there must be a greatest prime number. But Euclid proved otherwise and again we have a contradiction. So does the set of all prime numbers contain all finite elements with no greatest element? How is that possible?

Comment: Forget about the primes... How does the infinity of natural numbers look like to you? Will you present the same "arguments"?

Comment: An easier example to think about: The set of whole numbers consists of finite numbers and has no greatest element. If $N$ were the greatest element, then $N + 1$ is also a whole number but it is greater than $N$, a contradiction.

Comment: Your argument doesn't make any sense. You talk about having an "infinite prime number", but prime numbers are natural numbers *by definition*.

Comment: I think the question should not be down-voted as it is clear. I think we should just point out the mistake in the argument

Comment: Sets of natural numbers can be infinite, natural numbers cannot.

Comment: I upvoted just because OP put his question online ; I wouldn't have had the guts to do that if I had that question.

Comment: Notice that if every infinite set had an infinite element, then that element would itself have an infinite element and so on ad infinitum, which is absurd (at least in the usual modern conception of sets.)  Fortunately this is not the case.  In fact, the size of a set has nothing at all to do with the size of its elements.  Moreover in this particular case many people do not think of the elements (numbers) as having a size in the sense of cardinality at all.

Comment: I think the confusion of the OP is one reason why one should never say things like "the real numbers are uncountable" when one means "the set/class of real numbers is uncountable."  (In either of the two most common formulations, Cauchy sequences and Dedekind cuts, each individual real number _is_ countable, and in any case this is not what one usually means to talk about.)

Comment: I hope, at some point, there would be no more prime numbers. Just wondering, is it already proved?

Comment: This question was very edifying.

Comment: @vi.su. The opposite was proved 2,338 years ago.

Comment: There are primes, which are even numbers. But, the set of even numbers is not a number. We have a contradiction here. Primes must not exist.

Comment: "If we answer true, then there must be a greatest prime number" is unjustified.

Comment: The question makes no sense and should be highly downvoted.

Comment: What is a "finite number"? What is an "infinite number"?

Comment: The question should be downvoted because the description is not really a question, it's a poorly expressed argument consisting of a series of non sequiturs and absurdities, such as "If we answer true, then there must be a greatest prime number."

Note that there are infinitely many real numbers that >=0 and < 1. Consider how absurd the above argument would be in re that set ... there is of course no greatest real number < 1.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Every natural number is a finite number. Every prime number (in the usual definition) is a natural number. Thus, every prime number is finite. This does not contradict the fact that there are infinitely many primes, just like the fact that every natural number is finite does not contradict the fact that there are infinitely many natural numbers. You can have infinitely many finite things, and there won't ever be a biggest exemplar.

To make things a bit more complicated (and a lot more interesting), there are extensions of the set of natural numbers that do contain infinite numbers, and even infinite prime numbers. For instance, in any hyperreal extension of the reals, there is a system of hypernatural numbers. Some of these hypernatural numbers are finite and some are infinite. The finite ones are just a copy of the usual set of natural numbers and the primes in it are the usual primes. For the infinite hypernatural numbers, there are also prime numbers. For instance, the hypernatural represented by the sequence $(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,\cdots )$ is an infinite prime number.

Comment: If OP doesn't "get" the standard infinite sets and their _finite_ members, mixing in infinite numbers isn't the brightest idea of an explanation...

Comment: As I wrote in a now-deleted comment, one must resist the temptation of mentioning non-standard models. Those are delicate and confusing...

Comment: The first paragraph explains the situation clearly. The second one opens a door, and, perhaps, is appealing to some intuition OP has that while not standard is also not wrong. Especially that all the infinitude or primes together neatly come together to produce a single infinite prime number, quite like OP seems to think is the case without hypernaturals.

Comment: "You can have infinitely many finite" distinct integers? It would seem that because the minimum difference between any two consecutive elements is $1$, then eventually at least one element must approach infinity.

Comment: @cyclochaotic yes, there are sequences of (distinct, if you prefer) integers that approach infinity. On the other hand, any single fixed element is finite, and does not approach anything.

Comment: @cyclochaotic You seem to think of "approaching infinity" as getting "close to" infinity. This is not really the right way to think about it; since infinity is not a number, it doesn't make sense to think of particular numbers as being "close to" infinity. In other words, infinity isn't some sort of "ceiling" on the integers. Instead, it may be useful to think of "approaches infinity" as meaning "gets arbitrarily far away from 0."

Comment: "It would seem that because the minimum difference between any two consecutive elements is 1, then eventually at least one element must approach infinity." -- Each element is bigger than the previous one, so they all *approach* infinity -- or rather, *as a whole* they approach infinity. There's nothing special about any one of them.

Comment: I've always had a problem with infinity in mathematics (except in wooly as x->infinity sense). Eg, Can the members of the set of natural numbers be put into a one to one correspondence with the natural numbers? Natural numbers are not inifinite, but there are infinitly many of them... I've always had a problem with this kind of thing.

Comment: The first paragraph was a nice, simple answer.  The second paragraph crippled my mind.  The pages I Googled to try and figure it out finished the job and destroyed it.

Comment: I just realized we can think of this from the inverse. A set can have "infinitely many" finite non-zero elements, and there won't ever be a smallest exemplar. For example take the set of inverse squares $\left\{1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{25},\ldots \right\}$, not a single element is zero and we can add "infinitely many" smaller and smaller elements. Before this *exchange*, I would of thought eventually there would be infinitely many zero elements.

Comment: @cyclochaotic, the result of that is actually [an interesting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: ["So does the set of all prime numbers contain all finite elements with no greatest element? How is that possible?"]  HOW OR WHY WOULD IT NOT BE POSSIBLE is the question I would ask before answering

Comment: *Can the members of the set of natural numbers be put into a one to one correspondence with the natural numbers?* -- "the natural numbers" and "the members of the set of natural numbers" are synonyms, so of course they can be put into a 1-1 correspondence. *I've always had a problem with this kind of thing.* -- it's strange that you think this is a problem with mathematics, rather than a problem with you.

Comment: *take the set of inverse squares* -- or the set of reciprocals of any other set of natural numbers, e.g., 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, ... or 1/2, 1/3, 1/5, 1/7 ... *I would of thought eventually there would be infinitely many zero elements* -- how very strange.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I second your recommendation not to talk about non-standard models, even more so that the answer talks about a sequence representing a hypernatural but no one who does not know about ultrafilters and ultraproducts will ever understand what on earth it means.

Comment: @asteri: If you really want to understand the second paragraph, have a look at http://www.mcmp.philosophie.uni-muenchen.de/students/math/math_logic_munich.pdf (for basic first-order logic) and then http://www.people.vcu.edu/~bmcody/Compactness-Notes.pdf (for ultrafilters and ultraproducts). I found these free materials via Google. Ittay, I think your second paragraph would be more useful for readers of your answer if you add these links. =)

Comment: I don't really know that much about what a hyperreal number system is. You say the prime numbers can be extended to the infinite integers. How do you decide how to construct the hyperreal number system and decide when a number is an integer in that system? I guess that once you're already constructed multiplication, you can define a prime number the same way as a positive hyperinteger whose only positive integer factors are 1 and itself. The OP would probably also be thinking "Doesn't every computable function from the natural numbers to the natural numbers also have one and only one correct

Comment: extension to the supernatural numbers?" The first part paragraph would have been good as a stand alone answer. The later part I felt needed to be clear with what it's clearly explaining also being accurate. I actually downvoted this answer for that reason.

Comment: @Timothy I do not know what you mean by 'supernatural numbers'. You are free to downvote as you wish and whatever you found lacked clarity to merit that is, of course, your right as well. Will you kindly point out to anything that I said that was actually inaccurate so that I can correct it if needed.

Comment: I think supernatural numbers are defined to be positive infinite integers in the hyperreal number system.

Comment: @Timothy supernatural numbers, as far as I know, have little to do with the hyperreal number system. Supernatural numbers are more of an algebraic extension while the hyperreals involve an ultraproduct construction, a standard tool in logic.

Comment: "eventually at least one element must approach infinity" -- this is utterly incoherent. Individual numbers don't "approach" anything.

Comment: "I've always had a problem with infinity in mathematics" -- Jaydee seems to think that this is a problem with mathematics, when clearly it's a "you" problem.

Comment: "I actually downvoted this answer for that reason." -- Same here. The second paragraph is completely out of place and completely fails to consider the knowledge level and mindset of the OP.

Answer (score 56):

A prime number is an element of the set of all prime numbers, and as an element of that set, a prime number has no cardinality.

The ***set*** of all prime numbers is countably infinite (in *cardinality*, equal to $|\mathbb N|$): there are (adverb) ***infinitely*** many primes.

That's not to say there is a prime that is infinite. But you are correct that "infinity is not a number" here. The set being "infinite"  means that no matter how large a prime number you name may be, there is yet a larger prime than that...and after that, yet a greater prime, and so on. There is no end point at which you arrive at *the largest prime number.*

It is true that set of all prime numbers ***less than or equal to*** some positive integer $n$ is finite. But there are then infinitely many more primes greater than $n$, whatever particular $n$ you choose.

Comment: To add to the confusion, one can manipulate an object called 'infinity' in many ways similar to the manipulations that govern natural numbers. But one does not refer to infinity in common parlance as a number (presumably a natural number).

Comment: We do, though.  3 is a finite number. $\omega_0 + 3$ is an infinite ordinal number. The cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite cardinal number. And we say "a finite number of foos" very often, which is "speaking of a number being finite".

Comment: Yeah, natural number in Peano Arithmetic might not have a cardinality, but natural number as finite ordinal number in ZFC has a cardinality. But I don't know whether this is really related to the question of the OP. I guess the OP has another confusion and thinks the set of prime numbers is bounded, which would be possible for sets of ordinals, for example {0,1,...,omega}, the set omega+1 is bounded.

Answer (score 34):

> Are all prime numbers finite?

Yes.

> If we answer false, then there must be an infinite prime number.

That follows ... but we didn't "answer false", so we don't have to worry about it.

> But infinity is not a number and we have a contradiction.

Whether or not infinity is a number, there are infinite (or "transfinite") numbers. And even if there weren't, this still wouldn't be a contradiction, any more than "Not all horses are ugly" is a contradiction just because beauty is not an animal. This isn't about logic or math, it's about misuse of the English language. In any case, we didn't "answer false", so we don't have to worry about this supposed contradiction.

> If we answer true, then there must be a greatest prime number.

No, that does not follow at all. All primes are finite, but there is no greatest one, just as there is no greatest integer or even integer, etc. That there are infinitely many of something doesn't require that any of them be infinite, or infinity, or greatest.

Consider for instance the non-negative reals less than 1: `[0, 1)`. There are of course infinitely many of them, but they are all finite (less than 1, in fact), and there is no largest one. (Proof: suppose there were a largest one, L. Then (L+1)/2, which is halfway between L and 1, would also be in the set but would be larger than L. That really *is* a contradiction.)

> But Euclid proved otherwise and again we have a contradiction.

He did, but there is no contradiction.

> So does the set of all prime numbers contain all finite elements with no greatest element?

Yes.

> How is that possible?

There's no reason for it to be impossible, and Euclid proved it not only possible but true. You appear to have assumed it impossible in order to reach your conclusion of a contradiction, which is a circular argument.

Comment: "That there are infinitely many of something doesn't require that any of them be infinite, or infinity." So although there are infinitly many natural numbers, all of them are finite? So in what sense are there infinitly many? If I have 1,2,3,4 .... and all members of the set are finite, how are there infinitly many?

Comment: @Jaydee: Because there isn't a last one; there's always more. Suppose there were just a finite number of natural numbers, like 5,024. Then we couldn't have a 5,025th number. But that's absurd.

Comment: This is about logic and math. But most of your points are valid. Assuming a greatest element must exist is a misconception. In addition, I maintain that I communicated my perplexity very effectively via the English language.

Comment: 5024 & 5025 are both finite as is 5026, but that set only contains 5026 members, I'm not saying a maximum element must exist, I'm saying if you have an infinite number of different members of a set, then how can they all be finite?

Comment: Or to put it another way, each member of the set of natural numbers, identifies itself by its number. If ALL members of the set are finite, then the set must be finite. And vice versa.

Comment: @Jaydee. Think of it in terms of even numbers. There is a bag of natural numbers. I reach into the bag and grab a $2$ and put that into the set of even numbers. I reach into the bag again and grab a $4$, then a $6$, and so on. If I pull out a $2n$ and someone challenges me to find a greater even number, the natural numbers produces $2n+2$. The natural numbers has the property of being an unlimited source. We describe this by saying that the set of even numbers has *"infinitely many"* elements, yet every single element is finite!

Comment: First I'd like to thank you for taking the time to look at this. Sorry, I still don't get it. The set of natural numbers is 1,2,3,.... or 1 = member one, 2 = member two, 3=member three, etc. Each of these members is finite. I'm told that ALL natural numbers are finite. Yet there are an infinite number of members in the set. If so, how could I number the elements of set with natural numbers. I'd run out of natural numbers before I run out of members of the set which is, of course, absurd.

Comment: @Jaydee. For the moment forget about "an infinite number of members". Instead consider the fact that the number of members in a set must either be bound or unbound. For example, a bound set is all positive integers with one digit, $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. An unbound set would be all positive integers with more than 3 digits. For this set we can not say there are a finite about of members because we can **always find more members**. Therefore we say such a set has "infinitely many" members, but what we really mean is that the number of members is not bound.

Comment: " If ALL members of the set are finite, then the set must be finite." -- There is no basis whatsoever for that assertion, any more for the claim that someone who tends fat cows must be fat. Imagine that there were, in fact, some infinite set ... say the set of positive integers. What do we know about its elements? Well, we know that they are all finite, because all positive integers are finite. So, we have an example of an infinite set all of whose members are finite, contrary to your claim. If such a set cannot exist, it must be for some other reason than the one you claim.

Comment: "
  flag
 
This is about logic and math" -- Not the particular statement I identified. It's about language and I pointed out how. "But most of your points are valid." -- All of them are valid. "Assuming a greatest element must exist is a misconception." -- Well, no, it would be an erroneous assumption ... but who assumed that? "In addition, I maintain that I communicated my perplexity very effectively via the English language" -- I didn't say otherwise. I said that you *misused* the language; identifying the misuse leads to understanding the source of perplexity.

Comment: "I'm not saying a maximum element must exist" -- You have repeatedly said that ... e.g., "If ALL members of the set are finite, then the set must be finite" MEANS that there must be a maximum element. "I'm saying if you have an infinite number of different members of a set, then how can they all be finite?" -- That's not saying something, that's a rhetorical question. To say something would be to present an argument for why there's some contradiction in that statement ... but there isn't one; both finite and infinite sets of integers contain only finite numbers.

Comment: "Therefore we say such a set has "infinitely many" members, but what we really mean is that the number of members is not bound." -- No, this is wrong; a misuse of terminology. For instance, the set of real numbers [0,1] is infinite but bounded.

Comment: "What do we know about its elements? Well, we know that they are all finite, because all positive integers are finite." Then there must be a finite number of them. No?

Comment: I'll see if I can express my problem more clearly. Start with 1. +1=2, +1=3 +1=4... repeat +1 a finite number of times and you get a finite number of results each of which are finite. Where my problem arises is that for an infinite number of members, you need to repeat this (+1) an infinite number of times and when you do that the result cannot be finite.

Comment: @Jaydee. Maybe this freely available book on set theory will help, [Introduction to Modern Set Theory](http://www.math.ku.edu/~roitman/).

Comment: Many thanks. ..

Comment: @Jaydee "Then there must be a finite number of them." -- You keep saying that, but ... WHY? "No?" -- No. The two are completely unrelated ... what a set contains has nothing whatsover to do with how many things it contains.

Comment: @Jaydee "when you do that the result cannot be finite" -- No, you are incorrect. There isn't a result, there are results, each and every one of which is finite. The *number* of results is infinite, precisely because there is no last one.

Comment: +1 for cut and dry answers, but also for, "There's no reason for it to be impossible", even though that's about as satisfying as, "an infinite set is a set that's not finite" xD

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy My point with that comment is that Jaydee (or cyclochaotic) keeps saying that it's impossible, that sets that contain only finite members must be finite, but never offers any reason or explanation for the assertion. I think that, in order for Jaydee to progress, she or he must first take on the burden of proof and to stop with these unsupported assertions and rhetorical questions. When Jaydee says that a set consisting entirely of finite numbers must be finite, I offer, in order of strength, "Why do you think so?", "There's no reason for that to be true.", and "No, that's wrong."

Comment: @JimBalter I agree. Another way to phrase the burden of proof is, "If one exists, give an example of a natural number that is not finite".

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy Everyone agrees that all natural numbers are finite. The burden of proof is on those who claim that implies that all sets of natural numbers are finite (have finite cardinality).

Comment: "If one exists, give an example of a natural number that is not finite" How about "Start with 1. +1=2, +1=3 +1=4... repeat +1 an infinite number of times, to give an infinite numeber of members" then "There isn't a result, there are results, each and every one of which is finite. The number of results is infinite, precisely because there is no last one." I think my problem is in this. This is like having a stair case you take a step up, you take a step along, another step up, another step along.(result, member) but set theory say the staircase can be infitly long without being infinitly high.

Comment: Or alternatively, "If one exists, give an example of a natural number that is not finite". To which I would answer "precisely". Any algorithm that generates natural numbers will by your definition always generate finite numbers. If only finite numbers can be generated, the number of them must be finite. Yes, there may always be another generated, but it will be finite. To be perfectly honest, I think this kind of stuff is undecidable.

Comment: I think the terms finite and infinite are in fact unhelpful. I'm perfectly happy to say that the number of members has no limit and also that the "size" of the members has no limit.

Comment: I suspect I'm a finitist. See foundational issues http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set

Comment: " I think my problem is in this." -- No, your problem is that you refuse to pay attention. "set theory say the staircase can be infitly long without being infinitly high" -- No it doesn't say anything of the sort. It says that a tunnel or a beam can be infinitely long without being infinitely high. You keep insisting that, if it isn't infinitely high, it can't be infinitely long. "I think the terms finite and infinite are in fact unhelpful." -- yeah, right, the problem is with the words rather than with you, I'm sure.

Comment: "the staircase can be infitly long without being infinitly high" -- The correct statement is that, given an infinitely long and infinitely high staircase, no *individual step* is infinitely high ... nor, to reach that step, will you have gone an infinite distance. But because no step is the last step, the staircase itself is infinite.

Comment: @Jaydee *If only finite numbers can be generated, the number of them must be finite.* -- You repeated this many times,  each time told you are wrong, and asked to justify the claim, which you never did. Repeating unjustified claims is **bad** behavior ... it violates the rules of etiquette and rational inquiry, and leads to having a stunted intellect. *Yes, there may always be another generated, but it will be finite* -- Yes, it will, but as you were told many times, that has nothing to do with *how many* numbers there are. *To be perfectly honest* -- if I were, my comment would be deleted.

Comment: For another example, consider the set S[0] = 1, S[n] = S[n-1] + (2**-n). So, 1, 1.5, 1.75, 1.875, ... There are infinitely many numbers in the set, but they are all < 2. Or we could just consider the set of reals between 0 and 1 ... infinitely many, of course, but none infinitely large. The claim that an infinitely large set must have an infinitely large member is entirely baseless, no matter how many times it is witlessly repeated.

Comment: Every time I revisit this, I am again stunned by just how poor one of the commenter's cognitive skills are, coupled with immense arrogance--he's certain that he is right and math is wrong. No wonder that "After scraping through an engineering degree I spent a lot of my time working for accountants."

Comment: I do wish people would stop up voting this ... every time they do, I am reminded of how much I despise the arrogance of the gits that I responded to.

Comment: Ugh, another upvote and another tragic reminder that people like Jaydee exist.

Answer (score 3):

You can have an infinite number of objects, each with finite size, the sequence of which is not bounded, so yes all primes are finite... by definition of a prime number almost. It's meaningless to talk about a natural number being 'infinite' until you define that term.

Answer (score 3):

The modern definition of an infinite set is one which can be expressed in a one to one relationship with a subset of it self: eg: 2 4 6 8 and 1 2 3 4. this video produced by bbc horizon explores infitity, why there are at least two sizes of infitity... yup and many more aspects of infinity and its very wachable too... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiMigmLwwTM

The answer to your question is that you question is not a correctly stated mathematical problem in the english language. You are mixing up values within a set and the number of values within that set.

This response was written before the question was edited. Still recommend the video though.

Comment: That's inaccurate. The modern definition of an infinite set is a set which cannot be put in one-to-one correspondence with a bounded initial segment of the natural numbers. That is the canonical definition of finite. Dedekind infinite sets are those which can be injected into a proper subset. While the integers are certainly both, and assuming the axiom of choice every infinite set is Dedekind-infinite (and vice versa), when we say "infinite" we really just mean "not finite". Do note that we can characterize "finite" without appealing to the integers, Tarski has such a characterization.

Comment: Just to finish the above comment, Tarski's definition of finite is as follows, *a set $X$ is finite if and only if whenever $\mathcal U\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ is a non-empty family of subsets of $X$, then $\cal U$ has a $\subseteq$-maximal element.* This definition doesn't refer to the integers at all, and does not require the axiom of choice to be true. Interestingly, however, if we replace "family of subsets" by "$\subseteq$-chain" then one needs to use the axiom of choice to prove the equivalence.

Comment: The question wasn't edited, only the tags were. The original question was just as absurd as what we see here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you mean by number and in fact there are infinite *prime* numbers if and only if there are infinite *numbers*, by the tranfer principle. Namely, consider the first order statement that for every $n$, there is a prime $p$ greater than $n$. By transfer this is true for all $n$ including a particular infinite $n=H$.  But any prime $p$ greater than $H$ would also be infinite.